# moosefs - I have a few lingering files in the "sustained" folder (mounted -o mfsmeta), how do I clean up?

Tags: filesystems, moosefs

I've been cleaning up my mfs installation and found a few files showing up as "sustained" on the mfscgi list (I have disconnected a server that has these chunks), but also they show up in the mfsmeta filesystem, under "sustained".
How can I clean this up ?
Is this sustained folder subject to trash policies ?
Doesn't seem to allow me manual removal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sustained files in MooseFS are the files, which were deleted completely (from trash!) and are still used (open) by some process(es) on some mountpoints.

So you need to stop these processes which use these files in order to let them be deleted.

List of closed files is sent to Master Server regularly, so they should disappear from sustained soon (maybe with some small delay), especially if you unmounted the mounpoint.

You can check list of open files for particular mountpoint using `lsof -n | grep /mnt/mfs` or in "Resources" tab in MFS CGI.